# Use List of data from one web api to another api

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, web-applications, webapi

I have one api with name abc-api and in this I am getting records using following function. Now I want to use this data in another api, below is code I have tried..but can't use this data in that api..

```
public async Task<ICollection<CarrierCompilanceDocumentViewModel>> RefreshComplianceDocumentNotification(Guid tenantId, Guid countryId)
        {
            DateTime now = DateTime.UtcNow;

            var now1 = DateTime.UtcNow;

            var expiriesDays = new List<int> { 1, 7, 14 };
            var expiriesDates = expiriesDays.Select(x => now1.AddDays(x).Date).ToList();

            var carrierAdminUserEmails = _dbContext.CarrierUsers.IgnoreQueryFilters()
           .Where(x => x.IsAdmin)
           .Where(x => !x.IsDeleted && x.TenantId == tenantId && x.TenantCountryId == countryId)
           .Where(x => x.Carrier.ComplianceExpiryDate != null)
           .Select( x => new { x.Email, x.Carrier.ComplianceExpiryDate })
           .Distinct();

            return (ICollection<CarrierCompilanceDocumentViewModel>)carrierAdminUserEmails; }
```

Now I am getting in this carrierAdminUserEmails 3 values with Email and ComplianceExpiryDate.

Now I am calling this function from one another web-api and I want to use this values there..but I don't know how to use that..below is code I have done till now in that another web-api.

```
var client = _clientFactory.CreateClient("carrier");
            var request = HttpHelper.GetRequestMessageApiKey(_config, HttpMethod.Post,
            $"{_carrierHost}/api/cms/carrier-company/RefreshComplianceDocumentNotification?tenantId={tenantId}&countryId={countryId}");

            var response = await HttpHelper.GetResponseMessage(client, request);
            var result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

But not getting that 3 values in this web-api, any idea how to use that 3 values in this api.

Comment: How does your `(ICollection<CarrierCompilanceDocumentViewModel>)` cast even work from anonymous type you are selecting?

Comment: @zaitsman I have added explicit cast..if this is wrong..then what will be proper solution for this..let me know and also if you have any idea how can use this data in that next api.

Comment: @zaitsman I have changed that anonymous to viewmodel, so no need to add explicit cast..